# Reset password fail - iOS and Android app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, mobile

We are testing reset password function in app. Can reset expired password in webapp but unable to do so in mobile app.

Test:
Dev manually expired user password.
Opened up app and entered Username/Password - select login.
Get a pop-up that returns 'password expire, would you like to change it now?' Select Yes.
Enter Old and New password - Select update.

It recognizes the old password but fails to reset after entering new password.

However, able to reset in the webapp with no issues. Tested on iOS and Android.

Any suggestion or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Seriously?  You haven’t posted any code.  You haven’t told us anything about your auth mechanism.  How could we possibly answer?  Please read [ask] before posting